# Select row from data.table with min value

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` and I need to compute some new value on it and select row with `min` value.

```
tb <- data.table(g_id=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3),
          item_no=c(24,25,26,27,28,29,30),
          time_no=c(100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 160, 160),
          key="g_id")

#    g_id item_no time_no
# 1:    1      24     100
# 2:    1      25     110
# 3:    1      26     120
# 4:    2      27     130
# 5:    2      28     140
# 6:    2      29     160
# 7:    3      30     160

ts  <- 118
gId <- 2

tb[.(gId), list(item_no, tdiff={z=abs(time_no - ts)})]

#    g_id item_no tdiff
# 1:    2      27    12
# 2:    2      28    22
# 3:    2      29    42
```

And now I need to get the row (actually only `item_no` of this row) with minimal `tdiff`

```
#    g_id item_no tdiff
# 1:    2      27    12
```

Can I make it in one operation with `tb`? What is the fastest way to do this (because I need to do this operation about 500,000 rows)?

Comment: Are you looking for: `tb[.(gId), list(item_no, tdiff={z=abs(time_no - ts)})][,item_no[which.min(tdiff)],by=g_id]`

Comment: @GaryWeissman, thanks! I found that I can also write to the end of selection `[last(order(tdiff))][[2]]`

Comment: Glad to help! data.tables are great for this stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `.SD` and `[][]` chain query.

The problem to my understanding is that first you update an new column, then find the minimal tdiff

```
library(data.table)
tb <- data.table(g_id=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3),
             item_no=c(24,25,26,27,28,29,30),
             time_no=c(100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 160, 160),
             key="g_id")

ts <- 118

#　My solution is quite simple
tb[, tdiff := list(tdiff=abs(time_no - ts))][, .SD[which.min(tdiff)], by = key(tb)]
```

I think `.SD` is more appropriate. Also you can update using `:=`

and this is the output:

```
   g_id item_no time_no tdiff
1:    1      26     120     2
2:    2      27     130    12
3:    3      30     160    42
```

Answer (score 1):

The data.table calls can be chained together `[][][]` so all you need is an extra command to grab the minimum value for each `g_id`:

`tb[.(gId), list(item_no, tdiff={z=abs(time_no - ts)})][,item_no[which.min(tdiff)],by=g_id]`