# Select row from data.table in programming mode

Tags: r, data.table

You find the main part of my starting solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22728960/select-row-from-data-table-with-min-value). Now I would like to use it in program code and want to replace the column names by variables. Here is my MWE which throws errors in the last lines:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
tb = data.table(g_id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3),
                item_no = sample(c(24,25,26,27,28,29,30)),
                time_no = c(100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 160, 170)
                )

# get row with minimum value
# works
tb[, .SD[which.min(item_no)], by = g_id]
# now step by step with variables
mincol = "item_no"
grp = "g_id"
# works
tb[, .SD[which.min(item_no)], by = c(grp)]
# doesn't work
tb[, .SD[which.min(..mincol)], by = c(grp)]
```

Do you have any ideas to run this code with variables?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to use `which.min(get(mincol))` or `which.min(eval(as.name(mincol)))` in this case; support for `..mincol` shorthand is still not feature complete

Comment: `get`, of course! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to use `get`:

```
tb[, .SD[which.min(get(mincol))], by = c(grp)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of alternatives as well. The first method subsets the `.SD` using the extract operator `which.min(.SD[[mincol]])`:

```
#way 1
tb[tb[, .I[which.min(.SD[[mincol]])], by = grp]$V1] #or
tb[, .SD[which.min(.SD[[mincol]])], by = grp]
```

The second way uses `setorderv()` to update-in-place the dataset and then uses `unique` to further subset. Obviously, the reordering may not be a desirable side effect.

```
#way 2 that can produce a different order
setorderv(tb, mincol)
unique(tb, by = grp)
```